# Ejecutar un SweetAlert dentro de un echo

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

Quiero ejecutar un SweetAlert que estra dentro de un echo en php, pero me sale que la variable "swal" no está definida.

```
 echo '<script>
        swal({
            title: "",
            text: "Su solicitud se ha registrado correctamente " + solicitud,
            icon: "success",
            value: "confirm",
            buttons: {
                confirm: "Confirmar"
            }
        })
        </script>';
```

El Script de la libreria la estoy llamando al final de mi documento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es por la forma en como estás imprimiendo tu variable de tipo script

```
<?php

//Es una mala práctica poner aquí un echo con un script de librería, pero utilizalo como ultimo recurso por si no te lee las librerías desde otro archivo o al final. Lo dejé comentado porque esto no es parte del problema
#echo '<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>';

echo '<script>
var solicitud = "Hello world";
swal({
    title: "",
    text: "Su solicitud se ha registrado correctamente "'." + solicitud ".',
    icon: "success",
    value: "confirm",
    buttons: {
        confirm: "Confirmar"
    }
})
</script>';
```

Si te das cuenta he cambiado esta línea `text: "Su solicitud se ha registrado correctamente "'." + solicitud ".',` colocando comillas simples para que reciba bien la variable solicitud

Te adjunto un snippet HMTL (no php) donde coloco la librería al inicio ya que al final no la lee:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var solicitud = "Hello world";
    swal({
        title: "",
        text: "Su solicitud se ha registrado correctamente " + solicitud,
        icon: "success",
        value: "confirm",
        buttons: {
            confirm: "Confirmar"
        }
    })
    </script>
```